# Wordpress JSON API to POST custom field data

Tags: json, wordpress, postman

I'm using the Plugin JSON API and i can't post nothing on `"custom_fields"`.
On Postman (what i'm using to test) no matter what i put on value (i have tryied form-data and raw) but i can't post anything.

It stay on `"custom_fields": {}`

Comment: you dont need the plugin, its built into WP now called WP REST API

Comment: thank you! i'm new at this, can you help me? how do exactly i post with this API?

Comment: Look up a tutorial, there are lots out there for it now.